# Upgraded to Springboot 2 AbstractRoutingDataSource not working

Tags: spring-boot

Hi i was using Spring boot 1.4.0 it was working fine.

When i upgraded to Spring boot 2.0.0 its giving below error.

Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target DataSource for lookup key [null]

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:305)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:378)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:474)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:289)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.vega.ui.service.SecurityServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5fdaff4b.getTenantIdByUserName()

Here is my code to implement this

public class TenantContext {
    private static ThreadLocal currentTenant = new ThreadLocal<>();

```
public static void setCurrentTenant(Object tenant) {
    System.out.println("tenant : "+tenant);
    currentTenant.set(tenant);
}

public static Object getCurrentTenant() {
    return currentTenant.get();
}

public static void removeTenant() {
    currentTenant.remove();
}
```

}

public class TenantRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

```
String tenantId;

private Map<Object, Object> mRountingTargetDataSources;




public void setRountingTargetDataSources(Map<Object, Object> ptargetDataSources) {
    mRountingTargetDataSources = ptargetDataSources;
    this.setTargetDataSources(ptargetDataSources);
}

public Map<Object, Object> getRountingTargetDataSources() {

    return mRountingTargetDataSources;
}

@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {

    if (TenantContext.getCurrentTenant() != null)
        return TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
    else {
        return tenantId;
    }

}
```

}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @Autowired
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("dbTenantDataSource") TenantRoutingDataSource dataSource) {
        logger.info("Inside DataSourceTransactionManager");

```
    DataSourceTransactionManager dataSourceTransactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    dataSourceTransactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
    return dataSourceTransactionManager;
}
```